# GeoPandas: Split intersecting LineStrings and keep columns

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame with data from Open Street Map. I want to split all intersecting streets but keep the columns from the original splitted way.

**Example**
I want to split the way with the id 4294200 into 2 parts.

```
original_id         highway         lanes   geometry
4294200             motorway_link   2       LINESTRING (6.01706 49.51282, 6.01664 49.51293...
628218213           motorway_link   2       LINESTRING (6.01446 49.51440, 6.01435 49.51451...
```

[image]

**Expected result**

```
original_id         highway         lanes   geometry
4294200             motorway_link   2       LINESTRING (6.01706 49.51282, 6.01664 49.51293...
4294200             motorway_link   2       LINESTRING (6.01706 49.51251, 6.01652 49.51279...
628218213           motorway_link   2       LINESTRING (6.01446 49.51440, 6.01435 49.51451...
```

[image]

**Implementation**

```
import geopandas as gpd
data = gpd.gpd.read_file('luxembourg.geojson')

# split ways -> working
unary = data.geometry.unary_union
geometries = [i for i in unary]
ids = [j for j in range(len(geometries))]
unary = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id": ids, "geometry": geometries}, crs="EPSG:4326")

# join splitted ways with columns from original data frame (e.g. highway, lanes etc.) -> not working
joined = gpd.sjoin(unary, data, how="inner", op='within')

# this only contains 1 splitted way instead of 2
way_4294200=joined[joined['original_id'] == 4294200]
```

**Problem**
The data frame way_4294200 only contains one splitted way (green), the red one was not mapped correct.

```
original_id         highway         lanes   geometry
4294200             motorway_link   2       LINESTRING (6.01701 49.51221, 6.01636...)
```

[image]

What is the problem with the sjoin? Or is there a better way to split the geometries without losing the attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Having gone through your code it appears it is splitting the GeoDataFrame into individual geometries, but then you are only joining the first split geometry with the data GeoDataFrame. Use a for loop to iterate over each split geometry and join it with the GeoDataFrame.

```
import geopandas as gpd
data = gpd.gpd.read_file('luxembourg.geojson')

# split ways
unary = data.geometry.unary_union
geometries = [i for i in unary]
ids = [j for j in range(len(geometries))]
unary = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"id": ids, "geometry": geometries}, crs="EPSG:4326")
results = [] #empty list to store the results
for i in range(len(unary)):
    joined = gpd.sjoin(unary.loc[[i]], data, how="inner", op='within')
    results.append(joined)
joined = pd.concat(results)
way_4294200 = joined[joined['original_id'] == 4294200]
```